# Fetching database query through function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, oop, content-management-system

I am sick of connecting database in each script i need a more OOP approach to fetching database results. ex like wordpress use wpdb class to fetch results.

This what wordpress does to get data

```
<?php  $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'


 AND post_type='post' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0,4")
?>
```

How can i create the same feature too using any class or function

and use it in my script

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries out there. Some offer a little more and hence can be more complicated than others. I'm assuming you're looking for something more on the easier side.

You can actually extract wordpress' entire wpdb class and use it in your project. that class is actually a slightly modified version of [ezSQL](https://github.com/jv2222/ezSQL).

However, some other popular libraries include: [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), [PHP-Activerecord](http://phpactiverecord.org/). These go further than just allowing you to make simple query commands, they allow you to map your database to PHP objects. Many popular frameworks use them these days. If you're interested you can read more about the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) and [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

EDIT for: "How can I add wpdb class to my project?"

Pretty simple :). The wpdb class is held inside `wp-includes/wp-db.php`. You can include that file in your project. Then create a new object. Example below:

```
require_once('wp-db.php);
$db = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$yourtable}");
print_r($results);
```

That simple example should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help @kirill can you explain me a bit that how can i add wpdb class to my project.

Comment: @ShubhamMaurya Added the example to my answer. Hope this helps. Don't be afraid to dive into the wp-db.php file to see how it works :).

Comment: @kirril Thanks for the help. It surely gives me my answer but still i don't want too connect to database in each script. Is there any way that i connect my database once and use connection it in entire project.

Comment: @ShubhamMaurya You wouldn't have to, you can create one `wpdb` object and use it just like in wordpress. So you can declare `$db = new wpdb(...);` in the first file your loading in, and then in all other files you will be able to do `$db->get_results(...);`. You wouldn't have to do `$db = new wpdb(...);` in every file. Just once and as long as the `$db` object is available you will be able to create a new query with it. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah thank you very much. Can i use wordpress other classes in wp-includes like i used this one..????

Comment: @kirril i still can't run this code is give an error ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 4. plz HELP my line 4 is $db = new wpdb(......)